# React Select - type to search - Access to filterOption resulting array

Tags: reactjs, react-select

In React Select, my understanding is that I can provide the prop `options` to give an initial array of options to the select menu. Another prop that I am using is `filterOption` which I understand to be used in a map over all the initial options and called when user types to search.

My question is this: Is there a way for me to check the array of filtered options that react select is building while react select is doing the filtering?

I ask this because I have some options which have differing search key values but identical display values for business reasons. I want to be able to add a conditional statement (probably in filterOption?) that checks if the current item has the same display key as something that has already passed react select's filter.

Thanks!

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using `react-select` v2 ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `filterOption` as you describe.

By default `react-select` is searching in the `label` (what you called the display value) but you can totally create a filter function that look into the key `value` and will match the option that has a key value including the `inputValue` and also the other options that have the same label as the options matching like the following code:

```
const filterOption = (option, inputValue) => {
    const { label, value } = option;
    // looking if other options with same label are matching inputValue
    const otherKey = options.filter(
      opt => opt.label === label && opt.value.includes(inputValue)
    );
    return value.includes(inputValue) || otherKey.length > 0;
  };
```

Here a [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvjkjrqzjq) for the function below.

Comment: From my experience, by default, when searching, the filter is based on both properties of the data object : value and label. This default may cause undesired result when typing in certain input value, because it may be contained in the value property rather than in the label property. That's why I need this filterInput props to give me the desired result. But I thank you for providing example of filterOption which gives me a clue for me to solve my problem. I just need one statement in the filterOption function in my app :                return option.label.includes(inputValue).

Comment: Thanks! I was also trying to ignore the value in the option (which was giving false positives by matching in the uuid) and your example gave me the hint I needed to only check against labels: 

`const filterOptions = ({ label }, input) => label.includes(input);`